# Elapsed Days Hours Minutes Excluding Weekends and Holidays Time

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This sounds simple but I have been pulling my hair out trying to figure out a solution. Any help before I go bald would be great.

I need a formula which is able to

- calculate the duration in (days, hrs, mins) between two date\time values (eg `05/12/2012 5:30 PM` and say `07/12/2012 5:45 PM`);
- excluding weekends and holidays.

I would like the result of the formula to read as follows "e.g `2 Days 0 Hrs and 15 Mins`".

Thanks

Link to [sample workbook](http://www.excelforum.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=199111&d=1355089580)

Comment: To make it a little easier in the calculation, use the 2 hours prior to course end time as the reference point with 26 hours to mark as delivered. How exactly are you getting holiday data? It's not in any part of Excel or the operating system by default. The excelforum says that I'd need a login or such to get your sample workbook.

Comment: I'd start with `NETWORKDAYS` function.

Comment: @moshjosh You should post your data and/or spreadsheet on this site.  Linking to another forum is bad form.

Comment: Sorry to have been cheeky, I couldn’t figure out how to attach my file. I tried to upload a pic although I was told I couldn't because I’m a newbie. In any case please find the solution from that other "unnamed form". [see my post below]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following formula works like a treat with no additional formatting or manipulation.

To make it more stable I have turned all the holiday dates for UK 2012/13 into ‘Excel Serial Number’ format and placed them in an array bracket.

Replacing the "D5" in the formula with your cell reference for your course or metric "End Date" and "E5" with your course or Metric for "Completion Date".

```
=IF(E5<D5,"-"&TEXT(D5-E5,"h:mm"),NETWORKDAYS(D5,E5,({40910,41005,41008,41036,41064,41065,41148,41268,41269,41275,41362,41365,41400,41421,41512,41633,41634}))-1-(MOD(E5,1)<MOD(D5,1))&" days "&TEXT(E5-D5,"h:mm"))
```

Comment: I think you'll find @chris neilsen's answer is more flexible, and the one you should accept (click the check mark next to it). With this one you'll have to re-hardcode your holidays next year.

Comment: Thank you Chris, as said before I appreciate your input and time. For me, holidays included in the code are better, the code can then be moved from cell to cell; sheet to sheet without having to worry about the also moving the calendar dates range ($A$16:$A$24). I have included two years’ worth of holidays, more than enough for my need. Also it works for negative figures. As to what I accept, the solution was suggested for my purposes and surly I can decide what works better for my purposes?

Comment: Just to clarify, it was me who made the comment above, not Chris. I'm glad you got a solution that works for you!

Answer (score 6):

You can use `NETWORKDAYS` and `NETWORKDAYS.INTL` to achieve this

A bit of manipulation is required as these return net *whole* days:

- Use these functions to calculate the number of non workdays, then subtract from the difference between start and end dates

  ```
  =E3-D3-(NETWORKDAYS.INTL(D3,E3,"0000000")-NETWORKDAYS(D3,E3,$A$16:$A$24))
  ```

This returns the working day difference, where 1.0 = 1 day

- `NETWORKDAYS.INTL(D3,E3,"0000000")` calculates whole days between the two dates (no weekends, no holidays)
- `NETWORKDAYS(D3,E3,"0000000",$A$16:$A$24)` calculates whole working days days between the two dates (Sat/Sun weekends, holidays as per your list in `$A$16:$A$24`)
- Difference in non-working days between the two dates.
- `E3-D3` is time between start and end date/times (1.0 = 1 day)

---

Use custom number formatting to display thye result in the format you require

```
d "Days" h "Hours" mm "Mins"
```

Note: this format won't work for negative values, you will need an alternative for when end date is before start date.