# Determine working day include weekend but excluding holiday

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I am working with excel right now. And I have a problem with it. Here my problem that you may be able to help me.

Now, I must identify when is arrival date.

Example:

I have to send someting on friday, 20 january 2012. I need 3 days to send it. Then, monday, 23 january 2012 is holiday. 
If I calculate it manualy, it's very easy. I will get the answer that is 24 january 2012. But I dont know how to make formula to execute the case in excel.

Please help me guys.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe use `NETWORKDAYS` and/or `NETWORKDAYS.INTL`.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13795599/445425) for an example

Answer (score 0):

In Excel **2010** you can use `WORKDAY.INTL` function like

`=WORKDAY.INTL(A2,B2,"0000000",holidays)`

Where A2 is date and B2 days to add and holidays a range of holiday dates....but in Excel **2007** try this array formula

`=SMALL(IF(COUNTIF(holidays,A2+ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&B2*5)))=0,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&B2*5))),B2)`+A2

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

assumes that you never have more than 4 consecutive holiday dates (if you do then change *5 to *10 or higher)